# HTTP DELETE request produces status 501 not implemented in google chrome and firefox

Tags: angularjs, rest, google-chrome, http, firefox

I am building an application in angular js with REST api. When I emit this REST DELETE request

```
DELETE http://localhost:8080/api/users/testlogin HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://localhost:8080
X-CSRF-TOKEN: 0baaf5bf-b3bf-4a9b-a770-2ab3f50d153b
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36
DNT: 1
Referer: http://localhost:8080/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cookie: JSESSIONID=64D42E7FC0969F7F3960219309EFD0A4; remember-me=VDNpbGxmWC96clJESmNqU0d1bE0rUT09OkFHMFNxTnltRk5xMXVXVHNHRXFkNEE9PQ; CSRF-TOKEN=0baaf5bf-b3bf-4a9b-a770-2ab3f50d153b; NG_TRANSLATE_LANG_KEY=%22en%22
```

I get on Google chrome Version 49.0.2623.112 m (64-bit) and Firefox Developer Edition 47.0a2 (2016-04-12), the response

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/api/users/testlogin
Request Method: DELETE
Status Code: 501 Not Implemented
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:9614
```

The weird part is the same operation succeeded in IE 11. The request above works too when using [Advanced REST client chrome app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) (it produces status 200 and it does what it's supposed to do :) ).

In IE, the request contains

```
Request DELETE /api/users/testlogin HTTP/1.1
X-CSRF-TOKEN    d112e1f0-2b04-47a1-a8fb-4873c769ab2f
Accept  application/json, text/plain, */*
Referer http://127.0.0.1:8080/
Accept-Language fr-FR
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Host    127.0.0.1:8080
Content-Length  0
Connection  Keep-Alive
Cache-Control   no-cache
Cookie  remember-me=RGxLZ20vQXcrNVZEVXFFMVNyN2p3dz09OmRTNEtwZWErTitHRjg1MEJNTENXbUE9PQ; JSESSIONID=96484DEDF9D04D275DE43ADB186572C6; CSRF-TOKEN=d112e1f0-2b04-47a1-a8fb-4873c769ab2f; NG_TRANSLATE_LANG_KEY=%22fr%22
```

Code that performs Delete (angularjs v1.4.8) :
  Controller:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('UserDeleteController', function($scope, $uibModalInstance, entity, User) {

    $scope.user = entity;
    $scope.clear = function() {
        $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
    $scope.confirmDelete = function (login) {
        User.delete({login: login},
            function () {
                $uibModalInstance.close(true);
            });
    };
});
```

Resource:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.factory('User', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('api/users/:login', {}, {
        'query': {method: 'GET', isArray: true},
        'get': {
            method: 'GET',
            transformResponse: function (data) {
                data = angular.fromJson(data);
                return data;
            }
        },
        'save': { method:'POST' },
        'update': { method:'PUT' },
        'delete':{ method:'DELETE'}
    });
})
```

Any idea why this behavior ??

Comment: can you please post the result of: curl -v -X DELETE http://localhost:8080/api/users/testlogin

Comment: @apsillers, I edited the post to show IE 11 request header

Comment: In your IE request, you appear to issuing the request from `127.0.0.1`, but in Chrome, you are issuing it from `localhost`. Could that be related? the only other differenced I see are `Proxy-Connection` vs. `Connection` and the presence of `DNT`, and I don't easily see why either of those would affect server behavior, unless you're testing for them explicitly.

Comment: @thegio, it actually succeeded with curl with a great 200 OK. Thanks for that, I just confirmed that the problem is in the browsers but where ???

Comment: @apsillers, localhost is just an alias for 127.0.0.1, but like sometimes you met weird issues when programming I tested again with 127.0.0.1 but still nothing.

Comment: do you mind posting the code that performs the DELETE?

Comment: @thegio, code added. Hope it will be enough.

Comment: where are you injecting the X-CSRF-TOKEN? sorry for so much asking but is kinda wierd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by invalidating intellij cache and clearing browser cache too. Guess I'll need to add a cache buster in prod :).